# How to live check that element is empty with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

I have some block where i appending some html (span) depends on specify function. If this function is done i appends this span to div. But i need to append something elese if this function is't execute. So, my question is how to live check that in this div this span exist? This is my code:

```
if (...){
    $('.info_check').append('<span></span>');
}
```

...

```
    $('.info_check').on('DOMSubtreeModified',function(){
        if($(this).html() == "") {
            $('#instructions_panel').append('<span>...</span>');
        }
    });
```

i'v try with `:empty` and it's alos not working...

Comment: `$.has('selector')` or `$.children().length`.

Comment: $('.info_check').val() == '';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `if($(this).children('span').length==0)`

Comment: You really don't need the `== 0` part, just do `!$this.children().length()`

Comment: Good point ;) it just says literally what it does

Comment: it dost't work, this span is adding dinamicly by ajax so i need to check it live, this way changes anything

Comment: so you check it after each ajax execution?

Comment: if my function is't execute i'm not adding this span, so maybe this is the problem

Comment: from what you said it seems that you add span when function executes - `if (...)` - it's your function ? so what about `else {...}` ?

Comment: i don't know why but everything in else does't work, so i try to figure it out this way :)

Comment: ok i use this, for some other way but it's work, much thx

Answer (score 3):

```
if ($(this).is(':empty')) {...}
```

or:

```
if (!$(this).has('span')) {...}
```

or just:

```
if (!$(this).children().length) {...}
```

Comment: I was thinking there was an `$.is()` method. So many selectors... `:)`

Comment: it dost't work, this span is adding dinamicly by ajax so i need to check it live, this way changes anything

Comment: There's is no live checking of elements like this, you would have do it on an event or use a setInterval, which will be somewhat expensive. It looked like you where doing this on `DOMSubtreeModified`, and there's also a `onDOMnodeInserted` event etc.